# angular - *ngIf conditional based on url params

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-template

How can I show an element only if there are certain `queryParams` added to the url?

e.g.

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        console.log(params);
    });
}
```

And I want to do something like:

```
<div *ngIf="queryParams = 'query_name'"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to assign specific query param into a property and then use that property in the condition `*ngIf`.

```
queryParam;

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.queryParam = params['yourParamName'];
    });
}
```

In the markup

```
<div *ngIf="queryParam == 'yourCondition'"></div>
```

Comment: Yes, but that way it is always present. What I mean is, if the query is passed, show something.

Comment: No, if query param is not taken, `queryParam` will be `undefined` and the condition will result `false`

Comment: Sorry, I was refreshing with the query in the url. Thank You very much!

Answer (score 0):

in .ts file

```
private queryParams:string ='';

ngOnInit() {
    this.route.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
        this.queryParams= params['PARAMETER_NAME'];

    });
}
```

**For "PARAMETER_NAME" you can mention the name of the query parameter.
For example if route is "/userId"

```
this.queryParams= params['userId'];
```

in .html file

```
<div *ngIf="queryParams.toLowerCase() === 'QUERY_NAME'.toLowerCase()"></div>
```

**For "QUERY_NAME" you can mention the intended query parameter string.
For example if intended string is "userName"

```
 <div *ngIf="queryParams.toLowerCase() === 'userName'.toLowerCase()"></div>
```